# Use sed to fix broken newlines

Tags: bash, sed

I have a folder full of files, each with many hundreds of lines.  Many of these files have occasional broken newlines:  when I open them in vim, many have ^M^L interspersed where newlines should be.

In vim, I can run `%s/^M^L/\r/g` which will correct them.  However, I don't want to have to do this to every file.

So I'm trying to do this in a bash script via sed, but it hasn't worked.  I've tried both:

`sed 's/^M^L/\r/g' filename` and

```
sed 's/^M^L/\
/g' filename
```

Note: each time ^M^L appears here, I have done ctrl-v ctrl-m, not just shift-6 (^) M.

What am I doing wrong?  More to the point, what do I need to do for this to work?

Comment: linux - I'm not sure which distribution the server has installed.  I could find that out if it is important.

Comment: No.  That gives me what I need.  See below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
sed 's/\x0C//g`
```

or

```
sed 's/\x0D\x0C/\x0D/g'
```

or if you using GNU `sed`

```
sed 's/\r\f/\r/'
```

Comment: For posterity: I had to actually use sed 's/\x0C/\x0A/g` since these files were DOS formatted.  I hadn't noticed that until I was trying Karlson's answer.  Thanks! +1

Comment: Replacing page breaks with `\n`?